# How do i swap array elements in ember js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ember.js

I am new to ember js and I am trying to swap element using ember js but its not working. this is my code below.

```
function swap(arr) {
   let tmp = arr[evt.oldIndex];
   arr[evt.newIndex] = arr[evt.newIndex];
   arr[evt.oldIndex] = tmp;
}
```

I have look into ember array, and i can't seem to find good swap logic. there is no replaceAt etc. Seems messy when i try to hack around. I have googled but have not been able to find any answer.

Comment: can you add an example of output?

Comment: If possible, I would suggest adding a property to the elements of the array and then sorting based on that property. It would then be a matter of setting the property to the values you want.

Comment: @locks i guess i could try that but the current elements are just tagsinput objects. Is there no way to just easily swap the two elements without adding a key to sort the array? 

kp sigh The output is the same array, nothing is swapped.

Comment: Use can use es6 via babel like [arr[evt.newIndex], arr[evt.oldIndex]] = [arr[evt.oldIndex], arr[evt.newIndex]];

Answer (score 3):

There is a replace method implemented by Ember Array, and its spec is defined here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html#method_replace

So say you had an array with 4 items, and you wanted to swap 2 items at indexes 0 and 3, you could do something similar to the code that you have at the moment, but using replace, you might do:

```
const myArray = Ember.A([1, 2, 3, 4]);

const first = myArray[0];
const last = myArray[3];

myArray.replace(0, 1, last).replace(3, 1, first);
// mutates myArray and returns [4, 2, 3, 1]
```

You could then use this to define your own swap method in your own mixin, if you like.  Something like

```
swapItems(arrayToSwap, firstIndex, lastIndex) {
  const firstItem = arrayToSwap[firstIndex];
  const lastItem = arrayToSwap[lastIndex];

  arrayToSwap.replace(0, 1, lastItem).replace(3, 1, firstItem);
  return arrayToSwap;
}
```

Comment: This still did not work for me however, the replace got me think so for some reason the answer i posted works

Comment: Tried both and the winner is : [Double replace Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e9a7449eab938d0cdb1392a733099009?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Comment: Shouldn't that be ```const lastItem = arrayToSwap[secondIndex];``` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let temp = items.objectAt(evt.oldIndex);
    items.replace(evt.oldIndex, 1, [items.objectAt(evt.newIndex)]);
    items.insertAt(evt.newIndex, temp);
```

This method worked for swapping.

Comment: Good answer but this doesn't work because `insertAt` adds a new element instead of replacing it. If you have `[A, B, C]` and want to swap `(A, C)` you'll end up with `[C, A, B, A]`. For this to work, you need to use `replace` in both cases.